# In VSCode how can I open file from command line and find specified text?

Tags: visual-studio-code, command-line, editor

In Visual Studio Code,
How can I open a file in the command line
and specify a search string to position cursor?
(even with VS Studio already open (singleton mode))

I want something like:

```
code.exe prog1.py prog2.py --find "def/s+Cryptor(.*?):"
```

preferably search with a regex argument,
but this would also be fine:

```
code.exe prog1.py prog2.py --find "def Cryptor("
```